# Как найти разницу во времени между всеми записями таблицы, попадающими под условие и записями, которые идут следом за ними?

Tags: php, sql

Есть таблица "message", в которой записи хранятся в такой структуре:

```
ID, TIMESTAMP_X, M_NUMBER, T_ID, IS_LOG

 1. TIMESTAMP_1, 1, 1, 1
 2. TIMESTAMP_2, 1, 2, 0
 3. TIMESTAMP_3, 2, 1, 0
 4. TIMESTAMP_4, 2, 2, 1
 5. TIMESTAMP_5, 1, 3, 1
 6. TIMESTAMP_6, 3, 1, 0
 7. TIMESTAMP_7, 3, 2, 0
 8. TIMESTAMP_8, 2, 3, 0
 9. TIMESTAMP_9, 4, 1, 0
```

TIMESTAMP_X - время создания записи вида "13.09.2019 12:00:02"
Остальные поля varchar с числами

Для каждого уникального T_ID есть строки с M_NUMBER от 1 до N

Нужно найти строку, в которой IS_LOG = '1', выбрать следующую за ней по M_NUMBER, но с таким же T_ID, определить разницу во времени между ними. Так для всех T_ID.

В этом примере для T_ID = 1 это будет 1 и 3 строки, для T_ID = 2 это 4 и 7 строки, для T_ID = 3 это 5 и 8 строки и т.д.

Comment: Указывайте точно СУБД, включая версию. В общем случае - функция LAG().

Comment: Mysql 5.7.23-23

Comment: Ну тогда берите две копии таблицы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция LAG() в общем случае решает вопрос, в моём случае решилось так:

SELECT t.T_ID,TIMEDIFF(t2.TIMESTAMP_X,t.TIMESTAMP_X) AS time

FROM table AS t

LEFT JOIN table AS t2 
ON t.M_NUMBER + 1 = t2.M_NUMBER AND t.T_ID = t2.T_ID